# Android Butterknife null object reference error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, butterknife

I have an error in Android ButterKnife, using **androidx**  instead of **android**

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference**
**build.gradle(project)**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

**build.gradle(app)**

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

and error in fragment

```
@BindView(R.id.recyclerViewProduct)
RecyclerView recyclerViewProduct;
private Unbinder unbinder;
```

inflating view

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);
 unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
```

**I got an error here**

```
recyclerViewProduct.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

and i unbind

```
 @Override
public void onDetach() {
    unbinder.unbind();
    super.onDetach();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Double check if

`R.id.recyclerViewProduct`

is defined int the layout file fragment_product.xml.

Comment: Yep,i have added all view ids inside fragment with ButterKnifeZelezny

Answer (score 0):

replace butterknife libs by this

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc1'
kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc1'
```